# vestal_versions : problem with column named changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, vestal-versions

I am working with vestal version for 2 months. Everything was fine until this afternoon.
I didn't done anything special(or i don't remembered...) but the code works fine on others computers...

The problem is that i'm not able to save my model anymore: rails give me this error :   `ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: changes is defined by ActiveRecord`

changes field is by default an activerecord method.

With the console, the message is the next :

`ActiveRecord::DangerousAttributeError: changes is defined by ActiveRecord`

Here are my local gem files:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0.beta3)
actionpack (3.0.0.beta3)
activemodel (3.0.0.beta3)
activerecord (3.0.0.beta3)
activeresource (3.0.0.beta3)
activesupport (3.0.0.beta3)
arel (0.3.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (0.9.25, 0.9.24)
crack (0.1.7)
erubis (2.6.5)
god (0.9.0)
haml (3.0.1, 2.2.23)
i18n (0.3.7)
mail (2.2.0)
memcache-client (1.8.3)
memcached (0.17.7)
mime-types (1.16)
polyglot (0.3.1)
rack (1.1.0)
rack-mount (0.6.3)
rack-test (0.5.3)
rails (3.0.0.beta3)
railties (3.0.0.beta3)
rake (0.8.7)
savon (0.7.8, 0.7.6)
text-format (1.0.0)
text-hyphen (1.0.0)
thor (0.13.6, 0.13.4)
treetop (1.4.5)
tzinfo (0.3.20)
```

And here my Gemfile

```
source 'http://gemcutter.org'

gem "rails", "3.0.0.beta3"

gem "will_paginate", "3.0.pre"

#gem 'nokogiri'
#gem 'curb'
#gem 'handsoap'
gem 'savon'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'haml', '2.2.23'
#gem 'haml', '3.0.1'
gem 'hpricot'
gem 'i18n', '> 0.3.5'
gem 'i18n_routing'
gem 'i18n_auto_scoping'
gem 'handler301', :git => 'http://github.com/kwi/handler301.git'
gem 'seo_meta_builder'

gem 'vestal_versions'

#gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git', :branch => 'rails3'

## Bundle edge rails:
gem "rails", :git => "git://github.com/rails/rails.git"

## Bundle the gems you use:
# gem "bj"
# gem "hpricot", "0.6"
# gem "sqlite3-ruby", :require => "sqlite3"
# gem "aws-s3", :require => "aws/s3"

## Bundle gems used only in certain environments:
# gem "rspec", :group => :test
# group :test do
#   gem "webrat"
# end
```

If you have any suggestions to solve this issue, i'll be glad to hear them !

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a field in your model called changes. This is a bad practice as the attribute accessor will mask the original changes method. Methods of ActiveRecord::Base should never be used as column names within the database.

If you have not changed anything then it is odd that you are seeing this now. Have you upgraded your ActiveRecord gem perhaps, or renamed a column from something to changes.

The simplest fix, if this is acceptable to you is to rename your changes column within your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The column changes is provided by vestal_plugins, it's not my stuff :)
There were some bundle install performed today. 
Maybe there was an update of ActiveRecord ? Apparently somes files have been modified into my bundle gem directory concerning activereccord.
pfff it's the failure !
Thanks for your help. I'll try to fix it !

Comment: Arkannia, were you able to fix this?